# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on device ONLY

Tags: xcode, swift2, exc-bad-access

So after updating xCode to version 7.1 this morning, my project suddenly crashes and throws "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (CODE = 1)" anytime I access any part of an object in a submodule but ONLY when I build on an iOS device. In simulator, I can't reproduce the issue. I've checked for zombie objects in instruments and the app just crashes without producing any warning in instruments like it would when a zombie is found. I've cloned a new version of my repo and re-added the submodule thinking maybe it had something to do with xCode itself but the issue still persists. I decided I would try to access the object in appDelegate and even there, I get the same result. Here is where the issue was originally presented:
[image]

As you can see, there is absolutely no information as to what's causing it. I move up the stack trace and everything is in assembly. Abstract User is part of a submodule but has never presented any problems until the last update. Here is the stack trace:

- thread #1: tid = 0x14d13, 0x00000001011f5ad8 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_initStructMetadata_UniversalStrategy + 56, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x91)
  frame #0: 0x00000001011f5ad8 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_initStructMetadata_UniversalStrategy + 56
  frame #1: 0x0000000101162d14 libswiftCore.dylib`___lldb_unnamed_function201$$libswiftCore.dylib + 84
  frame #2: 0x00000001011f712c libswiftCore.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry* llvm::function_ref<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry* ()>::callback_fn(long) + 36
  frame #3: 0x00000001011f6fdc libswiftCore.dylib`swift::MetadataCache<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry>::addMetadataEntry(swift::EntryRef<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry>, ConcurrentList<swift::MetadataCache<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry>::EntryPair>&, llvm::function_ref<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry* ()>) + 156
  frame #4: 0x00000001011f3c50 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_getGenericMetadata + 416
  frame #5: 0x00000001011f3ccc libswiftCore.dylib`swift_getGenericMetadata2 + 24
  frame #6: 0x00000001010b1538 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift._NativeDictionaryStorage.maybeGet  (Swift._NativeDictionaryStorage)(A) -> Swift.Optional + 76
  frame #7: 0x000000010109f4e8 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift._VariantDictionaryStorage.maybeGet <A, B where A: Swift.Hashable> (Swift._VariantDictionaryStorage<A, B>)(A) -> Swift.Optional<B> + 92
  frame #8: 0x000000010109f440 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift.Dictionary.subscript.getter : (A) -> Swift.Optional + 168
  frame #9: 0x0000000100e3d2ec ServiceKit`ServiceKit.ServiceModel.init (dictionary=<unavailable>, self=<unavailable>)(dictionary : Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.AnyObject>) -> ServiceKit.ServiceModel + 316 at ServiceModel.swift:88
  frame #10: 0x0000000100e1e438 ServiceKit`ServiceKit.AbstractUser.init (dictionary=, self=)(dictionary : Swift.Dictionary) -> ServiceKit.AbstractUser + 180 at User.swift:36
  frame #11: 0x0000000100e205fc ServiceKit`ServiceKit.User.init (dictionary=<unavailable>, self=<unavailable>)(dictionary : Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.AnyObject>) -> ServiceKit.User + 344 at User.swift:744
  frame #12: 0x0000000100e26f48 ServiceKit`ServiceKit.ConsumerUser.init (dictionary=, self=)(dictionary : Swift.Dictionary) -> ServiceKit.ConsumerUser + 264 at User.swift:351
  frame #13: 0x0000000100e26e34 ServiceKit`ServiceKit.ConsumerUser.__allocating_init (dictionary=, $metatype=)(dictionary : Swift.Dictionary) -> ServiceKit.ConsumerUser + 88 at User.swift:0

  - frame #14: 0x000000010027910c Service.com`Service_com.SignInViewController.signUserIn (sender=0x0000000158576b70, self=0x000000015865a760)(Service_com.MKButton) -> () + 1416 at SignInViewController.swift:62
    frame #15: 0x0000000100279310 Service.com`@objc Service_com.SignInViewController.signUserIn (Service_com.SignInViewController)(Service_com.MKButton) -> () + 68 at SignInViewController.swift:0
    frame #16: 0x0000000189403cfc UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 100
    frame #17: 0x0000000189403c78 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
    frame #18: 0x00000001893eb930 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 416
    frame #19: 0x0000000189403590 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 572
    frame #20: 0x00000001894031c0 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 804
    frame #21: 0x00000001893fbcdc UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 784
    frame #22: 0x00000001893cc4a4 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 248
    frame #23: 0x00000001893ca76c UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5528
    frame #24: 0x0000000183df0544 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    frame #25: 0x0000000183deffd8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
    frame #26: 0x0000000183dedcd8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 724
    frame #27: 0x0000000183d1cca0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    frame #28: 0x000000018ef58088 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 180
    frame #29: 0x0000000189434ffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 204
    frame #30: 0x000000010029d09c Service.com`main + 136 at AppDelegate.swift:45
    frame #31: 0x000000019923a8b8 libdyld.dylib`start + 4

I've tried everything I can think of and followed numerous tutorials and debugging Bad Access errors and nothing helps. I almost feel like it's an Xcode issue but I have no idea. Here is the AbstractUser class if it helps:

```
public class AbstractUser: ServiceModel {

/// Date of last login
private(set) var lastLogin = NSDate()
/// Password (please, don't use this field stupidly...)
private(set) var password = String.empty

public struct SerializationKeys {
    public static let lastLogin = "last_login"
    public static let password = "password"
}


// MARK: - Copyable
public required init(source: Copyable) {
    super.init(source: source)

    let u = source as! AbstractUser
    lastLogin = u.lastLogin
    password = u.password
}


// MARK: - JSONSerializable
public required init(dictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
    super.init(dictionary: dictionary)

    lastLogin = lastLogin <|? dictionary[SerializationKeys.lastLogin]
    password = password <|? dictionary[SerializationKeys.password]
}

public override func toDictionary() -> [String : AnyObject] {
    var dictionary = super.toDictionary()

    dictionary[SerializationKeys.lastLogin] = lastLogin.toString()
    dictionary[SerializationKeys.password] = password

    return dictionary
}


// MARK: - ModelType
public override func updateObject(newVersion: ModelType) {
    super.updateObject(newVersion)

    let u = newVersion as! AbstractUser
    lastLogin = u.lastLogin
    password = u.password
}


// MARK: - NSCoding
@objc public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    lastLogin = lastLogin <|? aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(SerializationKeys.lastLogin)
    password = password <|? aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(SerializationKeys.password)
}

@objc public override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)

    aCoder.encodeObject(lastLogin, forKey: SerializationKeys.lastLogin)
    aCoder.encodeObject(password, forKey: SerializationKeys.password)
}
}
```

Also the User object is a subclass of AbstractUser and isn't the cause of the problem. It will produce the same error however just putting print(keys) after "let keys = ..." will cause the error just the same. The issue seems to be when I try and access any property or method on any class within that submodule.

Comment: you are using any other language other than english?

Comment: The stack trace suggests that there's something odd about a dictionary that's used at line 88 in ServiceModel.swift.  Have you tried debugging that?